# Mean value theorems for integrals on an open interval

Tags: calculus

In this Wikipedia link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), it says ``In general, if f : $[a, b]$ → R is continuous and g is an integrable function that does not change sign on $[a, b]$, then there exists $c$ in $(a, b)$ such that $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=f(c)\int_a^bg(x)dx$''

I wonder why they explicilty say $c$ is in the open interval $(a, b)$? As shown  in the following proof in that link, it seems if we can say $\int_a^bg(x)dx\neq 0$, then $c$ is in the closed interval $[a, b]$, isn't it?

So the only reason they say $c \in (a,b)$ instead of $c\in [a,b]$ is becasue of the special case $\int_a^bg(x)dx =0$? Any quick example of this special case?

Answer (score 0):

They simply want to emphasise the nontrivial case, as taking $c$ to be one of the endpoints makes the equation trivially true.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But i am too slow to understand why c takes endpoints is trivially true. Could you please explain more?